# Gatsby MDXRenderer: Error Element type is invalid: expected a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I have been working on a simple wiki style static page using gatsby.

versions:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@mdx-js/react": "^2.0.0",
    "gatsby": "^5.13.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-mdx": "^5.13.1",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^5.13.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  }
```

I already have almost everything working as intended, i have pages being created at build time from mdx files in a contents folder using MDXProvider in a template component and passing it children.

but now i have a landing page (index.js) for the website, where i have some custom components, and under the components i want to include some text which would also come from a mdx file in the content folder.
to render it i think i need to use MDXRenderer, but i keep getting the same error, no matter what i try.

error:

```
throw new Error('Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in ' + 'components) or a class/function (for composite components) ' + ("but got: " + (type == null ? type : typeof type) + "." + info));
```

to try and figure out if there might be some thing interfering i tried creating a very simple project using `npm init gatsby` but i still get the same error.

this is what i have so far:
index.js

```
import * as React from "react"
import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from "gatsby"
import { MDXRenderer } from "gatsby-plugin-mdx"

const IndexPage = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      mdx(frontmatter: {type: {eq: "landingPage"}}) {
        body
        frontmatter {
          title
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  return (
    <main>
      <h1>{data.mdx.frontmatter.title}</h1>
      <MDXRenderer>
        {data.mdx.body}
      </MDXRenderer>
    </main>
  )
}

export default IndexPage

export const Head = () => <title>Home Page</title>
```

gatsby-config.js:

```
/**
 * @type {import('gatsby').GatsbyConfig}
 */
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `My Gatsby Site`,
    siteUrl: `https://www.yourdomain.tld`
  },
  plugins: [
    "gatsby-plugin-mdx",
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        name: "pages",
        path: "./src/pages/",
      },
      __key: "pages"
    },
    // Add this new entry for the `contents` directory
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        name: "contents",
        path: "./src/contents/",
      },
      __key: "contents"
    }
  ]
};
```

landingPage.mdx:

```
---
title: Landing
type: landingPage
---

# Test
```

I have tried going through multiple gatsby/dependency versions, so far the only version that seems to work somewhat is when i use gatsbyv2 and accompanying plugins/dependencies, i am not too sure if i am missing something, i have tried looking through the documentation and i couldn't find anything that applies to my specific use case.

Comment: Can you please provide the full error message? Context is important.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is that the API for `gatsby-plugin-mdx` has changed from version `4.0.0` and no longer supports this way of using `<MDXRenderer>`. If you revert to an earlier version (try `3.20.0` for instance) then your approach should work. Update the other package versions accordingly. This is what a working set of dependencies might look like:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "0.5.10",
    "gatsby": "4.25.8",
    "gatsby-plugin-mdx": "3.20.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-netlify": "5.1.1",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "4.25.0",
    "@mdx-js/mdx": "1.6.22",
    "@mdx-js/react": "1.6.22",
    "react": "17.0.0",
    "react-dom": "17.0.0",
    "slash": "5.1.0"
  }
```

With something similar in place your approach should work.

See [this](https://datawookie.dev/blog/2024/02/gatsby-content-from-mdx/) for more details and a link to a repository with a complete working test site. ⚠️ That post actually has details of how to do this using both the old and the new `gatsby-plugin-mdx` API.